# How can i use the gotoAndStop function and frame label in subclass in actionscript3?

Tags: actionscript-3

Actually in my timeline totally 5 frames are present. Having two movieclips in first frame, If I pressed an any of the one I need to go to third frame in the timeline. I am getting error when I am using this code in Sub class

```
public function Game(num:uint):void
        {
            if (num == 1)
            {
                gotoAndStop("Gameplay");
            }
        }
```

Kindly help me how to do this in subclass.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where does this class live?  is it your document class?  is it tied to a display object on your main timeline?   More information is needed

Comment: Yes this is document class, also it is in main timeline I am trying to move to next frame. how it is possible in document class.

Comment: If it is your document class, then the code posted should not throw an error so long as you are extending `MovieClip` and **not** `Sprite` -  eg `public class Game extends MovieClip`

Comment: This is not document class. The code I am trying to access is in  sub class

Comment: That contradicts your previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function Game(num:uint):void
        {
            if (num == 1)
            {
                gotoAndStop("Gameplay");
            }
        }
```

You are getting error cause of this : `gotoAndStop("Gameplay");`

If you have different Scene's on your project, you need to use this gotoAndStop/Play like this : `gotoAndStop(1,"Gameplay");`

If you have only frames in one scene then you can use like this : `gotoAndStop(3);`

If you want to control stage inside any of your mc's then u should use like this : `MovieClip(root).gotoAndStop(3);`

Hope it help and if u have any question about this write below :)